# bifurcation analysis for 1 dimensional ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would go about answering this question?

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \mu x  - \frac{x^3}{2} + \frac{x^5}{4} $$

$\mu$ is a parameter and x is a real number.  Classify all bifurcations of equilibria and, in the process of doing this, determine
all equilibria and their stability type.

I know the fixed points are $x = 0$ and $\mu=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4} $

Comment: In the latter case you have not really identified the fixed points: you should have $x(\mu)$, not $\mu(x)$. Once you have the fixed points $x(\mu)$ you can think about when they collide, which is when bifurcations occur.

Answer (score 2):

First solve the equation
$$
\mu x  - \frac{x^3}{2} + \frac{x^5}{4}=x\left(\mu  - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4}\right)=0
$$
for each $\mu$ and then see how the phase portrait changes with $\mu$. Namely, $x=0$ or
$$
x^2=-1\pm\sqrt{1-4\mu}.
$$
So you get $1$ equilibrium when $\sqrt{1-4\mu}\le 1$ and $3$ equilibria when  $\sqrt{1-4\mu}> 1$. The rest is just a matter of looking at the phase portraits.